# Understanding import attributes of electronics speakers, by example

Tags: noise, driver

I'm new to electronics/robotics and I'd like to start with a simple project that uses a speaker to play sound clips when a certain event/input/stimulus is detected.

Looking on Digi-Key and similar sights, there's a billion little two-wire speakers like [this one](https://www.visaton.de/en/products/drivers/miniature-speakers/k-15-s-8-ohm), but I'm not sure how to make sense of their characteristics/attributes to determine whether they will suit my needs or not.

Are all speakers capable of producing just about *any* sound, if driven correctly? Or are different speakers "capped" to simpler sounds, like the typical 8-bit audio sound of older video games? What characteristics of speakers determines what kinds of sounds they are capable of playing?

For instance, on Digi-Key, you can search for speakers by a large variety of attributes, such as:

- Series (Agile, APS, ASB, etc.)
- Technology (Magnetic vs Piezo)
- Type (Exciter, General Purpose, Subwoofer)
- Frequency Range
- Impedance
- Efficiency
- list goes on

Again, I'm just looking for a speaker that *can* play some sound clips (that I'll probably record on a computer or phone). Once I know that I'm dealing with a speaker that *can* play sound clips, I'll start dealing with the headache of figuring out how to drive it and get it to play them.

**I do need a small speaker that can fit on a small (bread loaf-sized) hobby project.**

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small speaker like [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/7950) one should be able to play tunes as you have mentioned. You can use an arduino or a raspberry-pi to stream audio over as shown in [this](https://extramaster.net/tools/midiToArduino) link.

Comment: Thanks @Akhil (+1) -- but _why_ would that speaker be able to play the tunes I mentioned? What characteristics/qualities does it possess (that other speakers might _not_ possess) that allows it to do this?

Comment: I am not entirely sure, but the description says that it can play tunes and interfaces well with microcontrollers. The only criteria I used for the search was the audible range and small size you mentioned.